# Is there any way to decrease screensaver timeout every time my watch is moved away from the computer or phone?

Tags: iphone, security, privacy, screensaver, watchos

Using the watch to unlock my Mac is a great feature, but I want the OS to shorten the idle time once the watch goes out of range.

This way, if I'm wearing the watch, and I'm not facing the computer (I'm behind it), there is less of a risk of unintended use or disclosure of what's on my screen.

- Is there any way to control this, or to set up a script that will achieve similar results?

Perhaps I can hack something together if the MacOS can "ping" the watchOS. It's my understanding that's how watch unlock works... an 802.11 "distance ping" is done between the two hardware devices.

**Edit:**

If you are a [beta](http://beta.apple.com) user, and want this feature, please create feedback in the feedback app, and reference #320354 in your product suggestion /

[image]

[image]